# Jersey, HTML button calls Java method

Tags: java, html, maven, jersey

I have to make a project for my study exam with using Grizzly server and Jersey. The server is set up and runs perfectly and uses my HTML file to create the website. Now I want to make a button that calls a Java method on click.

Here is the Grizzly server:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URI baseUri = URI.create("http://localhost:9998");
    final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(Homepage.class);
    final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, resourceConfig);
    System.out.println("Starting grizzly ...");

    Homepage hp = new Homepage();
    hp.sayHelloInHtml();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Stop Server");
    server.shutdownNow();
}
```

Here is the `Homepage.java` code:

```
@Path("")
public class Homepage {

@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public String sayHelloInHtml() throws IOException {
    String content = Files.toString(new File("homepage.html"), Charsets.UTF_8);
    return content;
}

public void btnClicked(){
    System.out.println("Button clicked!");
}
```

}

And this is the `homepage.html` code:

```
<HTML>
  <BODY>
    <H2>
        Hello World
    </H2>
    <button>
        Click Me!
    </button>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

So when I click the button <kbd>Click Me!</kbd> I want to call the method `btnClicked()` in the class `Homepage`.

Do I have to make any type of client or something? Never worked with Jersey and we need to do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your method. on button click call action with the url /btnClicked

```
@Path("/btnClicked")
@GET
@Produces("text/html")
public void btnClicked(){
    System.out.println("Button clicked!");
}
```

Comment: Wow that worked just perfectly, thanks alot =)

Also can I combine it somehow with a textfield? So I can type in the textfield what System.out should print and with the button I can submit it to the method to print that text?

Comment: Ok nevermind I finally managed to find it out =)
With the JAX-RS Annotation @FormParam I can call the value of the named textfields.
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/
Here is the link to the site if someone needs to know.

Comment: @DragonBale Good to hear that solution worked for you. Please accept the answer. Thanks